# Adding part of the text from Textarea colored/highlighted somehow

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well, I would like to hightlight part of the text in a textarea tag, like facebook does it when you are linking someone in your status update. how do I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is very likely a [tag:javascript] problem. You should tag that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What facebook do is they have a div sitting under the textarea which updates on keyup on from the textarea, which can obviously use tags and css to change how the text looks, they wrap the highlighted words in b tags which have background: *lightbluecolor*; font-weight:normal

So your markup would look something like this

```
<div class="highlight">
    hi <b>Dave<b> how are you?
</div>

<textarea></textarea>

.hightlight { position:absolute }
.hightlight b { font-weight:normal; background:#FEFAE2 }

$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    // do stuff with detecting the mentions but essentially:
    $('.highlight').html($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need the help of Javascript to do this. Because the solution is, I believe, a bit too complex for this Q&A site, I would suggest Googling tutorials, for example: http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1192. There are also some great examples for you to examine: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/htmlArea

from the website

> With this very basic plug-in, you can allow any HTML inside a textarea
>   - with full jQuery UI Theme support.
>
> It's as simple as $("TEXTAREA").htmlArea();
>
> There are many options you can set, the colour of the text, position,
>   show formatting options etc. etc.
>
> $("TEXTAREA").htmlArea({color:'#FF00FF',align:'right'});

Comment: Hey bro, that seems to be the answer, but in this jquery project you gave me theres no link to download, could you get me one that I can actually test? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is in your stack, this plugin should do the trick for you:

https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-highlightTextarea